# Draw rout in titanium Map

Tags: android, ios, iphone, google-maps, titanium

this is my code:

```
var win = Ti.UI.createView({
    left : 0,
    top : 0,
    right : 0,
    top : 0
});
Ti.UI.currentWindow.add(win);

var mapview = Titanium.Map.createView({
    mapType : Titanium.Map.STANDARD_TYPE,
    region : {
        latitude : 0,
        longitude : 0,
        latitudeDelta : 1,
        longitudeDelta : 1
    },
    animate : true,
    regionFit : true,
    userLocation : false,
});
win.add(mapview);

currenposition();

function drawrout(longitude, latitude) {

    Titanium.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e) {
        if (e.error) {
            alert('HFL cannot get your current location');
            return;
        } else {
            var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
            xhr.open('GET', "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" + latitude + ',' + longitude + "&destination=" + (latitude - 0.01) + ',' + (longitude - 0.01) + "&sensor=true");
            xhr.onload = function() {
                var xml = this.responseText;
                var points = [];

                // Bellow Variable have the step of the current location to destination  Location. Using the Steps we going to create a route.

                var position = JSON.parse(this.responseText).routes[0].legs[0].steps;
                if (position[0] != null) {

                    points.push({
                        latitude : position[0].start_location.lat,
                        longitude : position[0].start_location.lng,
                    });

                    // Here we use the for loop to collect all the steps and push it to the array and use this array to form the route in android.

                    for (var i = 0; i < position.length; i++) {

                        points.push({
                            latitude : position[i].end_location.lat,
                            longitude : position[i].end_location.lng,
                        });
                    }
                } else {
                    alert('no route');
                }

                var route = {
                    name : "india",
                    points : points,
                    color : "red",
                    width : 5
                };

                mapview.addRoute(route);
            };
            xhr.send();
        }
    });
}

function currenposition() {

    Titanium.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e) {
        if (e.error) {
            alert('HFL cannot get your current location');
            return;
        } else {
            var longitude = e.coords.longitude;
            var latitude = e.coords.latitude;
            mapview.region = {
                latitude : latitude,
                longitude : longitude,
                latitudeDelta : 0.01,
                longitudeDelta : 0.01
            };

            drawrout(longitude, latitude);
        }
    });
}
```

white this code I get sum line between two points but the rout is not god defined
[image: this is the complete rout]

[image: detailed image]

like we can se it on the images the rout is defined by some points and a line between them. how can i get all points of the street so a can draw the line on top of the road?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem following this link:

https://archive.appcelerator.com/question/141002/plot-a-route-on-google-map-in-android#answer-245304

Answer (score 1):

For each step in XML response there is a polyline tag.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#sample-response

You need to decode all polylines and add all the points of all the polylines in a point array.
http://thesundarnataraj.blogspot.it/2012/11/decoding-polylines-from-google-maps.html

Then you can use this array to make the route.